# Edit and update of user info. in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise for user management so it let's user sign up with default email and password fields.

I added new fields/columns into the user model say username, designation and company.

So I have a profile view say with route '/users/1' and a link_to helper which would allow me to edit and update my user info.

By default i can only use users/edit route to edit my user info. How can i manage a new or separate edit and update option with different route say '/users/1/edit' from my profile view.

I read some posts before this but didn't help me. If anyone could outline things i should do. Thanks for reading :))

**Edit:**

routes file

```
root 'public#index'
devise_for :users
resources :users do
  put 'users/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit'
end
```

user controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update ]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end

  def show
    authorize @user
  end

  def edit
    if current_user == @user
      @user.update()
    end
  end

  def update
    authorize @user
    if @user.update(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def secure_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:designation, :company,      
        :username)
    end

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

In my view to go to edit:

```
<% if current_user.id == @user.id %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit My profile', edit_user_path(@user), method: :edit, 
  class:"btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you mean you want to [set up an admin role](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial) ?

Comment: @LamPhan no not really. just that every individual user can update their own user info later on. just like how we can edit our profile to complete user details in social media.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would want that? If you want to allow the user to update only his profile and not any other, why do you want to specify the user's ID in the route? By using `users/edit` devise can figure out which user is currently logged in and edit that user. Please let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @crodev I agree and you are correct. But I just wanted to know how I could modify the custom devise routes based on my convenience if I wanted to and if possible. maybe i am wrong.

Comment: I mean if you REALLY want the `user/:id/edit` route you could just make one yourself? Have a `user/:id/edit` route which points to a `users#edit` action in your users controller, and then do the logic there. If you are interested in that kind of an approach, I can write an answer on that if you want to.

Comment: @crodev an answer would be great. it'd help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have a route `user/:id/edit` and not use the Devise default `users/edit` route(which edits the currently logged-in user). You can do the following:

Let's assume you have a users controller(if you don't have one, create one) and add an `edit` action to it which will handle the editing logic:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # other code
  def edit
    user = User.find_by(id: params[:id]) # this id will be passed through the route
    
    # Now here you need some authorization logic to prevent users from updating others.
    # If you use CanCanCan, Pundit or any other authorization gem then write
    # this logic there

    if current_user == user
      user.update() # do your update logic here with params you have

      # render some json or whatever you want
    else
      # render some error messages in format you are using
    end
      
  end
end
```

This is the controller logic, now in your `routes.rb` file you need to register this route:

```rb
put 'user/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit'
```

This will edit the user with ID specified at `:id`.

**Note again**: This is not the approach I would take, I would rather just use the `users/edit` route and update the currently logged in user, but you wanted an example of this so do as you will

Comment: I am getting no "No route matches [POST] "/users/1/edit". i have my updated question. could you tell me what went wrong? @crodev

Comment: @goku You set up a PUT route—appropriate for a form submission with a PUT verb, not appropriate for a link, which is a GET request.

Comment: @DaveNewton is it the way in my view that i am getting it wrong? sorry but i  am still in the process of figuring it out.